# Why does 8-bit MUL combine into AX but 16 and 32-bit MUL leave their result split between [E]DX:[E]AX?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, x86-16, multiplication, instructions

- `MUL CL` CL is BYTE size and it equals to  `AX = AL * CL`
- `MUL BX` BX is WORD size and it equals to `DX:AX = AX * BX`
- `MUL EBX` EBX is DWORD size and it equals to `EDX:EAX = EAX * EBX`

I want to know why the 8-bit size [`MUL`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul) instruction gives the result in `AX` and not in `DL:AL`?

Is it because for 16-bit MUL, result can be `EAX`, for 32-bit MUL result can be `RAX`, but for 64-bit `mul rcx` there wouldn't be be any single register wide enough to hold the result?

Comment: `MUL` is an instruction, not a function. And there's no eax, ebx or rax in 8086

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 8086 had 16-bit registers (AX, BX, ...).  So an 8*8=16 widening multiply (that is, with 8-bit inputs and a 16-bit result) could fit its result in a single register.  Splitting it across two registers would have been inconvenient and provided no benefit.

But the 16*16=32 widening multiply could not fit its result in a single register, because there were no 32-bit registers.  By necessity it had to be split across two registers, and DX and AX were chosen.

Likewise, the 386 had 32-bit registers (EAX, EBX, ...), so its 32*32=64 widening multiply had to have its result split.  EDX:EAX were chosen for similarity with 8086.

Intel could at this point have added a new version of the 16*16=32 MUL which left its result in a single 32-bit register such as EAX, but they chose not to, perhaps for compatibility or to avoid unnecessary extra complexity, or from simple inertia.  So the 386's 16*16=32 `MUL` still leaves its result split across DX:AX, even in 32-bit mode.

(They did, however, add a non-widening 32*32=32 form of the signed multiply `IMUL` instruction, which leaves its result in a single 32-bit register.  One can use this for signed 16*16=32 multiplication by sign-extending the inputs, for which the convenient `MOVSX` was also added.  And it can be used for 16*16=32 unsigned multiply, by zero-extending the inputs, if one knows that the product will be less than `2^31`.)

Likewise again, x86-64 had 64-bit registers.  For the existing multiplication instructions, they kept the behavior the same (so 32*32=64 still splits its result across EDX:EAX instead of using a single 64-bit register), and they added a 64*64=128 widening multiply which, again, must split its result, and leaves it in RDX:RAX.  And there is also a non-widening 64*64=64 signed `IMUL` which leaves its result in a single 64-bit register.

Comment: Actually, "for similarity" is an understatement: the 32-bit MUL instruction (for a 32-bit segment) is encoded exactly the same way as the 16-bit counterpart (for a 16-bit segment). The behavior is mostly the same: the difference is only in width of the operands.

Comment: so if 8086 had 32 bit registers like EAX,  we can change that ```DX:AX``` with ```EAX``` and it will work right ?

Comment: @LesBenjamim: See update.  They could have done that with the 386 but they didn't.

Comment: @NateEldredge yeah that is what i thought they could but they didnt want it. Okay man thank you for your answer1

Comment: Note that `imul r64, r64` works totally fine with two 32-bit unsigned inputs that have been zero-extended to 64-bit.   https://godbolt.org/z/xM8PT1 shows GCC and clang doing that for `a * (uint64_t)b`.  The sign bits of the wider registers will always be clear, so they'll be treated as signed-positive (thus with the right values).  The difference between signed and unsigned multiply in the upper half is only because of the interpretation of the MSB of the inputs.  "signed overflow" of the product (MSB set) doesn't do anything (e.g. `0x00ff * 0x00ff = 0xfe01` with imul r16,r16) except FLAGS.